# fetch data firebase and write text react native

Tags: react-native

I want to pull data from the Firebase database and print it to text, but I can't pull the data. I cannot print any data to Text. Where's my problem?
I cannot print the data I have taken to the text, I cannot extract the data. I added the Firebase data table to the photos.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvtMp.png)

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    items: []
  };

     db.ref('/TBL_SIPARISLER/AD/0/').on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let items = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({ items });
    });
render() {
    return (  <View style={stylesNew.container}>
        {this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
          <ItemComponent items={this.state.items} />
        ) : (
          <Text>No items</Text>
        )}
      </View>
}
```

**İTEMSCOMPENENT.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class ItemComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemsList}>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemsList: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  itemtext: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```